# Renaming namespaces in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, namespaces, renaming

Is it possible to rename the namespace, projectfolder, solution name in windows phone? I have a paid version and free version of app. The free version of the app has minor modification. So I tried copying the whole project folder of the paid version and tried renaming the namespace, solution name, foldernames. I landed up in a bag full of errors!!

Is there any way i can do this? or do I have to do it the hard way?, have to create a new project and files and Ctrl+C the whole content???

Could someone help me on this?

Alfah

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to rename the solution and project? If you want to change the name of the app, you just have to edit the manifest file.

If you really want to change the namespace, you can use Visual Studio's refactoring features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx

Comment: I have both free and paid versions of the app. So renaming the project folders and namespace makes it easier. I renamed name space the Manifest file and when i try to run. I get an error called MisssingManifestResourceException. I have a resx file. Any changes that i need to make there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a 3-step process:

1. Rename all the namespaces, references, configuration etc (basically, everything you can find through full solution code search). Make sure it compiles.
2. Close solution. Rename files on the disk. Open the solution file in the Notepad, update the renamed folder references. Make sure that after opening the solution in VS it opens correctly.
3. In the project properties, select the Startup Object (http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/12/fixing-wp7-app-not-starting-after-project-rename/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely you can!
Please refer following steps

1. Open LocalizedStrings.cs and refactor namespace from it.
2. Rename project solution
3. Expand properties and open AppManifest file
4. Change the display name and tile title
5. Right click on solution file and select clean solution from contextual menu.

Here you are ready with your project with new name! Enjoy!